# Foreground service is stopped when app get crashed

Tags: android, service, android-service, foreground, background-foreground

I have a service running in  Foreground 
this is not stopped if I close the app,
now I check what happen if the app crashes and the service is stopping.

I dont want it stopped,
how can I avoid the service stopped when app crashes?

I set this code in a button for cause app crashes

```
float resultado= 3/0;
```

then the service is stopped

Comment: Did you find solution?